# Why can't I hear the sounds when making a call?

Tags: pi-3b+, gsm

I was able to make calls using my RPI 3 model B+, Huawei E153 GSM Modem, and minicom.

I can see that the cellphone I'm calling was able to answer my call (from my Pi). I plugged in my headphones to the RPI but I can't hear any sound. Even if I talk the other party can't hear me.

I should mention I connect to my Pi via SSH and that's where I run minicom and issue AT commands.

I wonder what else should I do?

Comment: have you enabled Audio in Rpi advanced settings? https://support.screenly.io/hc/en-us/articles/214547803-How-do-I-enable-analogue-audio-output-for-my-Raspberry-Pi-

Comment: i will check that. but i remember i played the example file using oxmplayer but i was able to hear the sound of the mp3 file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to make a call using `ATD`, `ATA` or `ATS0` commands, bear in mind that these commands instruct the modem to make a call **using its own audio inputs/outputs**. They will work as expected if your modem is a mobile phone (and you will be able to speak to / hear the other side using the phone), but they will do nothing on a device which provides only data. They are there just for compatibility reasons.

Plugging a microphone and a speaker into the RPi will not help.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think I will have to use this shield instead: https://www.itead.cc/raspberry-pi-sim800-gsm-gprs-add-on-v2-0.html

Comment: @r2b2 Yep, that board seems to have its own audio jacks, and if it has Bluetooth, you may be able to get the call audio into the RPi, (if the board supports BT audio profiles).